# JSP file keeps crashing every time I run it. What is going on?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, struts2

I have a JSP file that keeps crashing every time I run it. I am using the *Eclipse IDE* and the *Struts2* jars. I pulled this project from StarTeam repository which was uploaded by a team member. This project works completely fine on his computer.
But it doesn't on my machine. I keep getting an `there is no action mapped` error.

```
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/Users/jujaray/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpwebapps/Temp%20Code/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:6:56
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Action class [actionPackage.AccountLoader] not found - action - file:/C:/Users/jujaray/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpwebapps/Temp%20Code/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:6:56
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:482)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:426)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:552)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:258)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 17 more

Jan 29, 2014 10:08:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/Users/jujaray/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpwebapps/Temp%20Code/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:6:56
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/Users/jujaray/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpwebapps/Temp%20Code/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:6:56
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: Action class [actionPackage.AccountLoader] not found - action - file:/C:/Users/jujaray/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpwebapps/Temp%20Code/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:6:56
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:482)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:426)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:552)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:258)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Well if the original was not editing fodder, I don't know what is.

Comment: There are repeated mentions of WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:6:56. Is that file valid and well formed?

Comment: Can you post the first 10 lines of your struts.xml? Looks like at line 6 you have some kind of error. BTW, do you have ALL the libraries in your WEB-INF/lib?